Client certificate Code not working in .net 8
I've encountered an issue where I need to include a client certificate when making calls to my Azure APIM. Everything functions correctly when using Postman or C# code written in .NET Framework 4.8. However, when attempting to execute the same code in .NET 8.0, it fails to work.
Does anyone have any insights into why I'm unable to successfully send my request with the client certificate?
Below is the code snippet for reference.
 var cert = new X509Certificate2("D:\\MyFolder\\MyCertificate.pfx", "certificatepassword");
 var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
 handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
 handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
 var client = new HttpClient(handler);
 var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://APIMURL.com");
 request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "key");
 var content = new StringContent("{\"action\":\"myaction\"}", null, "text/plain");
 request.Content = content;
 var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
 response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
 Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());


What error do you get?

For .NET 8, the following may be of interest: TLS/SSL best practices

Given works for me in .Net8 too @mike. Can you share the error message if any

Your code did work for me in .NET8.
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

var cert = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\afreen12-MyCertificate-20240426.pfx", {certificatePassword});
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://{apim_Name}.azure-api.net/echo/resource");
request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "02ca*********7753");
var content = new StringContent("{\"vehicleType\": \"train\",\"maxSpeed\": 125,\"avgSpeed\": 90,\"speedUnit\": \"mph\"}", null, "text/plain");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

.csproj-
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

I am able to get the expected output.

Please check if you are using the correct credentials like certificate password, Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key.
